# Is there a workaround to call RegisterAsyncJsObject multiple times while using CefSharp Browser in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am using the CefSharp browser in an open source project of mine; a markdown editor to preview the markdown like in the screenshot below:
[image]

The relevant XAML is as follows:

```
<dragablz:TabablzControl TabStripPlacement="Top" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentDocument, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="TabDocuments" FixedHeaderCount="{Binding CurrentPreferences.IsTabBarLocked, Converter={StaticResource LockTabBarConverter}}">
    <dragablz:TabablzControl.HeaderItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" MaxWidth="10" MinWidth="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" MaxWidth="10" MinWidth="10"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Metadata.FileName}"/>
                <Thumb Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource InvisibleThumbStyle}" dragablz:DragablzItem.IsCustomThumb="True">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseDocumentButtonCommand}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Thumb>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="*" Visibility="{Binding IsSaved, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Width="10" Height="10" MaxWidth="10" MaxHeight="10" MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding CloseDocumentButtonCommand}">
                    <TextBlock Text="X" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="8" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dragablz:TabablzControl.HeaderItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="TabDocumentsDataTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5">
                    <customControls:CodeTextboxHost Text="{Binding Markdown, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                    History="{Binding History, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                    RedoStack="{Binding RedoStack, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                    FilePath="{Binding Metadata.FilePath}" 
                                                    WordWrap="{Binding IsWordWrap, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                    Font="{Binding CurrentFont, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                    x:Name="CodeTextboxHost"/>
                </Border>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
                    <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser Address="{Binding Html, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="ChromiumWebBrowser" Loaded="ChromiumWebBrowser_OnLoaded"/>                           
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</dragablz:TabablzControl>
```

I am now implementing scroll sync. However it is not very straightforward as it is not possible to interact with the browser scroll bars as a normal control. Fortunately, CefSharp browser provides a way to run JavaScript and to link certain classes with certain JavaScript objects. I was able to implement the scroll sync from the textbox control to the browser using these methods.

However I am having issues while implementing the scroll sync from the browser to the textbox control. I will give a brief summary of what I did so far first.

On every document's HTML file I have the following script:

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    var maxValue = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].scrollHeight - document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
    var minValue = 0;
    var value = e.target.body.scrollTop;

    cefChromimumBrowser.browserScrollChange(value, maxValue, minValue);
}
```

This script gets the max value, min value and the actual scroll value and sends it to the C# side. To make the "transfer", I have an event listener which performs the following when the browser is first loaded:

```
private void ChromiumWebBrowser_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var browser = (ChromiumWebBrowser)sender;
    browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("cefChromimumBrowser", CefChromiumBrowserManager.GetInstance());
}
```

This, registers `cefChromimumBrowser` object that I have in the JavaScript as an instance of `CefChromiumBrowserManager`. In `CefChromiumBrowserManager` I have a method such as this:

```
public void BrowserScrollChange(int value, int maxValue, int minValue)
{
    var scrollResult = new ScrollResult
    {
        MaxValue = maxValue,
        MinValue = minValue,
        Value = value
    };

    SharedEventHandler.GetInstance().RaiseOnBrowserScrollChanged(scrollResult);
}
```

When the `OnBrowserScrollChanged` event is raised, it changes the scroll position on the textbox control.

This works perfectly when there is only 1 tab. As soon as I open another tab I got the "Browser is already initialized. RegisterJsObject must be called before the underlying CEF browser is created." error.

I checked the CefSharp documentation and this is indeed the case, the browser is initialized once per application which is discussed [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1076). And it is only possible to use RegisterAsyncJsObject right after the browser is first initialized, which is documented [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage).

So I tried a second approach, thinking maybe if the registered JavaScript is the same, it would pick it up without registering it again:

```
private void ChromiumWebBrowser_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_isBrowserInitialized)
    {
        var browser = (ChromiumWebBrowser)sender;
        browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("cefChromimumBrowser", CefChromiumBrowserManager.GetInstance());

        _isBrowserInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

I got rid of the error but now the scroll only worked in the first tab and it didn't work in the rest of the tabs.

My question is; can I somehow transfer the "register" to the second tab (or the active tab if there are multiple tabs) so that the scroll sync from browser to textbox works?

Comment: Actually according to docs `RegisterAsyncJsObject()` "registers a Javascript object in this specific browser instance." so if for rest of tabs if you are initializing another browser instance then the instance of `CefChromiumBrowserManager` is not available with it.

Comment: So how you are opening/creating browser for another tabs does matter, which is not shown in question.

Comment: As you can see from the XAML, the browser control is inside a `DataTemplate`. The problem here is WPF tab control has a feature called virtualization. It uses the same control for every tab but changes the binding parameters. So the control gets "loaded" as a new tab is opened but since it was initialized when the first tab was opened I am unable run the RegisterAsyncJsObject() method again for the new tab. There is [a way](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460989/WPF-TabControl-Turning-Off-Tab-Virtualization) to break the virtualization but it may break the other controls in the tab.

Comment: when you scroll on second tab are you getting `cefChromimumBrowser is not defined` error in browser console?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see it because remote debugging cannot be enabled through dependency properties. And I cannot re-initialize at the "loaded" event to setup remote debugging either.

Comment: In loaded event try calling `browser.ShowDevTools();` to open developer tool

Comment: When I scroll on the second tab I get the Uncaught "ReferenceError: cefChromimumBrowser is not defined at window.onscroll"